# PlasTeX doesn't manage to generate images

Tags: windows, latex, tex

I'm trying to use PlasTeX to convert some .tex files into html pages.

Here is my testing.tex

> \documentclass{article}
>   \usepackage{mypackage}
>   \begin{document}
>   Hello 
>   \begin{equation}
>   23+40+29+29+10+60+33)/7=32
>   \end{equation}
>   \end{document}

but it seems there is an issue when it tries to convert the equation in a image to put in the html
Here  is the result of the command-line in windows cmd : plastex testing.tex

> C:\Temp\DiveIntoPlastex>plastex
>   testing.tex plasTeX version 0.9.1  (
>   c:\python24\lib\site-
>   packages\plastex-0.9.2-py2.4.egg\plasTeX\Packages\article.pyc
>   ) (
>   C:\Temp\DiveIntoPlastex\src\mypackage.pyc
>   ) INFO: Directing output files to
>   directory: testing. INFO: Importing
>   templates from c:\python24\lib\site-
>   packages\plastex-0.9.2-py2.4.egg\plasTeX\Renderers\PageTemplate INFO: Importing templates from
>   c:\python24\lib\site-
>   packages\plastex-0.9.2-py2.4.egg\plasTeX\Renderers\XHTML
>   INFO: Importing templates from
>   C:\Temp\DiveIntoPlastex\render INFO:
>   Importing templates from
>   c:\python24\lib\site-
>   packages\plastex-0.9.2-py2.4.egg\plasTeX\Renderers\XHTML\Themes\default
>   INFO: Using the imager "dvipng".  [
>   index.html ]This is pdfTeXk, Version
>   3.1415926-1.40.9 (Web2C 7.5.7)  %&-line parsing enabled. entering
>   extended mode **kpathsea: Running
>   mktextex images.tex ! I can't find
>   file `images.tex'. <*> images.tex**
>   (Press Enter to retry, or Control-Z to
>   exit) Please type another input file
>   name:

in fact, plastex manages to write an html but instead of the equation there is an empty image with the source code of the equation.

Somebody as an genius idea ????

Ps:I precise i am now seeking a solution for 2h on the internet but I have not found something relevant...

Answer (score 1):

I never used PlasTeX before but this is what I've tried and it worked just fine.

I wrote this code on a file "test.tex"

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

Hello \\

$\frac{23}{7} = 32$

\end{document}
```

Then I've compiled just like you did:

```
plastex test.tex
```

Everything went fine and I get a folder named test with html equivalent of the document.